# Rendering a form from another app in the template of another Django app

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to render a newsletter app form on my pages app `index.html` template in the same project, but for some reason, the form is not displaying on the homepage. Please, can someone help as I am fairly new to using Django.

this is my `pages\views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from newsletter.forms import JoinForm

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'pages/index.html')
```

this is my `newsletter\views`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Join
from .forms import JoinForm


def newsletter_signup(request):
    form = JoinForm(request.Post or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=false)
        if Join.objects.filter(email=instance.email).exists():
            print("This email already exists")
        else:
            instance.save()

    context = {'form': form,}
    return render(request, 'pages/index.html', context)
```

this my `pages\index.html` template:

```
<form action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ join }}
        <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Subscribe</button> 
</form>
```

and this is my `newsletter\forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Join

class JoinForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Join
        fields = ['email']

        def clean_email(self):
            email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
            return email
```

thanks.

Comment: The template variable containing the form is `form`, not `join`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks a lot! It's now rendering fine.